# How to concatenate JObects

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a couple JObjects that are being returned from different places but that have all the same properties.  I need to concatenate/merge this into one larger jObject.  Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

I want it to have all the same proerties as the individual objects. For instance.

```
jObject1 = { "data": [{"name": "foo","id": "1234" }]};
jObject2 = {"data": [{ "name": "foo2", "id": "5678" }]};
```

Resulting in something like this.

```
jobject3 = { "data": [{ "name": "foo", "id": "1234"}, { "name": "foo2", "id": "5678" }]};
```

I'm coding in C# and the only thing I have thought about doing so far is something like this which isn't valid.  Not really sure how to begin and can't really anything.

```
jobject3 = jObject1.Concat(jObject2);
```

I am trying to manually loop through each object and build a new object.  I think I am close but keep getting an error when adding the second item (oAlldepartment.Add) saying "Can not add property  to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.".

dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(people);
foreach (var item in dynObj.data)
{ 
    string id = item.id;
    string name = item.name;

```
department = getdepartment(id);

JObject oDepartment = new JObject();

try
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(department))
        oDepartment = JObject.Parse(department);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

JArray departmentArray = new JArray();

if (oDepartment != null)
{
    foreach (var x in oDepartment["data"].Children())
    {
        try
        {
            JObject departmentObject = new JObject();

            ((JObject)departmentObject).Add(new JProperty("name", x["name"]));
            ((JObject)departmentObject).Add(new JProperty("department", new JObject(new JProperty("name", x["department"]["name"]))));
            ((JObject)departmentObject).Add(new JProperty("hire_date", x["hire_date"]));
            ((JObject)departmentObject).Add(new JProperty("description", x["description"]));
            departmentArray.Add(departmentObject);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        ((JObject)x).Add(new JProperty("itemtype", "post"));
    }
    try
    {
        oAlldepartment.Add(new JProperty("", new JArray(departmentArray)));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Thanks,

Rhonda

Comment: Define "concatenate," as you use it here. What structure would this larger object have? Specific properties? Or should it be an array?

Comment: I want it to have all the same proerties as the individual objects.  For instance.

jOject1 = { "data": [{"name": "foo","id": "1234" }]}
jOject2 = {"data": [{ "name": "foo2", "id": "5678" }]}

concatenated object

jobject3 = { "data": [{ "name": "foo", "id": "1234"}, { "name": "foo2", "id": "5678" }]}

Comment: If you update your question with this information in an easy-to-read format, you are more likely to get an answer. Especially if you describe what you've already tried, and where you're having difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a class that defined the json I wanted to return and adding the json properties from each indivual object.  The other benefit is my data returned by the method to the client is cleaner as I only have to worry about the properties I need instead of a huge json object with a bunch of properties that I don't need.

Rhonda